# Location div moves to a different place that specified in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My location div that I have created moves to the right of the title header instead of going to the right of the about div.

https://jsfiddle.net/j0j4xfLe/3/

```
<div id="location">
        <h3 class="content-title">Where are we?</h3>
        <p id="locationMap">Google Maps</p>
        <p id="locationAddress">Location</p>
</div>
```

^^This is the location div^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your heading was not on the same level as the other areas you wanted to include on the grid, so it assumed that that was an empty space with nothing that matches that name.

```
updated fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mpua900b/